# Word for teaching moral lessons annoyingly

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that I can use to describe writing that explicitly tries to make us learn moral lessons which could be boring?

Comment: _Sanctimonious_ usually works well, albeit carrying connotations of superiority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Didactic* writing might be the term you are looking for.

[***didactic***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/didactic)

> Inclined to teach or moralize excessively.
>
> *(Literary & Literary Critical Terms) (of works of art or literature)* containing a political or moral message to which aesthetic considerations are subordinated

Answer (score 7):

*[Preaching](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/preaching)* is sometimes used for this:-

> v.tr.
>   1. To proclaim or put forth in a sermon: preached the gospel.
>   2. To advocate, especially to urge acceptance of or compliance with: preached tolerance and peaceful coexistence.
>   3. To deliver (a sermon). v.intr.
>   1. To deliver a sermon.
>   2. To give religious or moral instruction, especially in a tedious manner.

(especially in the second sense of the intransitive).

One might also call it *[hectoring](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/hectoring)*, [to intimidate or harass by bluster or personal pressure](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hector), which is sometimes used for particularly forceful, patronising or repetitive preaching.

Answer (score 5):

Such writing could be termed **prescriptive**, **preachy** or **sermonic**.

Comment: Can you add citations and examples? *Sermonic* looked particularly interesting.

Answer (score 2):

**Pontificating** is a favourite of mine. It implies that the speaker is taking a similar assumed moral stance to the Pontiff - i.e. the Pope.

Answer (score 1):

How about a phrase? *trite, facile sermonising*

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is teaching moral lessons to you patronizingly, they may be *on their high horse*.

Answer (score 0):

The word is *fable* or *proverb*, but you might have to tack on an adjective to get the proper connotation of insufferable sanctimony.